# in python is there a way to show CLI app to someone who doesn’t have python installed

Tags: python, command-line-interface, rendering

well I made something and want to show it to some of my friends but since they are not into coding they don’t have python installed in their computers is it necessary to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your program into an executable so it eliminates the Python installation dependency.

Ref - https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/